# Lambda function that checks whether one of three strings are in a line

Tags: python, lambda, pyspark

So I haven't used lambda functions much and my professors is pushing that we use them so I'm struggling a bit.

I'm working in Pyspark and I need to check whether one of three words are in a line and count how many times they show up. Here is my current attempt:

```
lines = sc.textFile("File")    
counts = lines.filter(lambda line: "x" or "y" or "z" in line.lower())
counts.count()
```

When I do this, the count is equal to the total number of lines which isn't correct.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `"x" in ... or "y" in ... or "z" in ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with using lambdas. The problem is that you're using the wrong syntax to test multiple strings. You can't put `or` between each of the strings, you need to do that between the comparisons.

```
counts = lines.filter(lambda line: "x" in line.lower() or "y" in line.lower() or "z" in line.lower())
```

To simplify it, you can use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any%60)

```
counts = lines.filter(lambda line: any(x in line.lower() for x in ["x", "y", "z"]))
```

Comment: Wow, had no idea about the `any` function. Thanks for the concise response.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `"x" or "y" or "z" in line.lower()` is always `True`. Any nonempty string is 'Trueish' in Python and the Boolean expression `True or ...` is always `True`, no matter what follows the `True`.

Better way: Use Python's `any`

```
lines = sc.textFile("File")    
counts = lines.filter(lambda line: any(c in line.lower() for c in ["x", "y", "z"]))
counts.count()
```